# Replacement for css unit of measurement with .css() method?

Tags: jquery, css

Using `.scrollTop()` to change the margins of an element via `.css()` so that it floats up when the page is scrolled but only at the top. HOWEVER, I want to cap it at a certain margin value so that if the user scrolls back up between the values that make it float it doesn't keep moving.

Problem is, how? If I'm using `vh` in my `css`, even `px` don't work. What unit or other means could be used to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var floater = $('#BLOCS_s1-img5');

   $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if ( 
         ( $(document).scrollTop() > 50 && $(document).scrollTop() < 350 ) && 
         ( floater.css('margin-top') >= -35vh )
       ) { 
         floater.css('margin-top','-=2');
         }
   });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='BLOCS_projSample'>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img4' src='images/Blocs2_logo.jpg'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img5' src='images/Blocs_pp_singleMonth.jpg'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img1' src='images/Blocs_pp_hpStack.jpg'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img2' src='images/Blocs_pp_hp.jpg'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img3' src='images/Blocs1_home.jpg'/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#BLOCS_s1-img5 {
    width: 16vw;
    position: relative;
    margin: -17vh 0 0 30vw;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you used -35vh, I think it's not valid in jquery

Comment: yeah, pretty sure it's not. I just threw that in because that's what I was using in my css. But that right there is the missing link. I need to figure out what unit of measurement (or other way I haven't thought of) to cap the margin-top of that element.

Comment: To get view height in jquery you can use $( window ).height();, in your case you can use (35 * $( window ).height())/100  instead of 35vh and for more please upload your code snippet with html and css  so that we can provide you more better solution

Comment: @nidhi does that help? Still can't get anything with $(window).height() to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in jquery `floater.css('margin-top') >= -35vh` doesn't work because

**1.**  as i 
commented `vh` dosen't work in jquery for that you have to use `$(window).height()`, which gives full window height that is equal to `100vh` as per css value, so to get -35vh you have to use `-(35 * $( window ).height())/100` which gives equal value of -35vh .

**2.** `floater.css('margin-top')` gives `px` value of margin top but here we compare this value with `-(35 * $( window ).height())/100` which has no unit(like `px`) so we can't compare these two value,  so here we convert `floater.css('margin-top')` in to integer value using `parseInt`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var floater = $('#BLOCS_s1-img5');
    var maxVH =  -(35 * $( window ).height())/100;
    floater.css('margin-top', -(17 * $( window ).height())/100);

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {

        if ( 
            ( $(document).scrollTop() > 50 && $(document).scrollTop() < 350 ) && 
            ( parseInt(floater.css('margin-top')) >= maxVH )
        ) { 
            floater.css('margin-top','-=2');
        }
    });

});
```

```css
#BLOCS_s1-img5 {
    width: 16vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='BLOCS_projSample'>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img4' src='https://img.tutpad.com/tut/0/280/cover.jpg?size=548x'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img5' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN2AQWvohSCMmWXmoquRs6Qx8fkMP-52C8R4Izdu6Vd0mZCdfp8Q'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img1' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/093/616/non_2x/square-aztec-pattern-vectors.jpg'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img2' src='http://www.mygraphichunt.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wpid-colorful-funky-chevron-pattern-vector.jpg'/>
    <img id='BLOCS_s1-img3' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/102/849/non_2x/vector-free-colorful-flat-herringbone-patterns.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! parseInt() was the other missing link! Thank you!